# PowerQuery passing list of operations as a parameter, how to make dynamic?

Tags: powerquery

I wanted to change this custom function's ColumnName into ColumnNameList, a list of column names, and have the Table.TransformColumns list of operations be generated from that list of column names.

```
        (Table as table, ColumnName as text) as table =>
            let
                #"Cleared Column" =
                    Table.TransformColumns(
                        Table,
                        {
                            {
                                ColumnName,
                                each null
                            }
                        }
                    )
            in
                Table.ReplaceRows(
                    #"Cleared Column",
                    0,
                    1,
                    {Table{0}}
                )
```

Is it possible to create a list of operations, that wouldn't evaluate the function i need to zip in the operation list?   If I tried to use List.Transform each null... it would give me a list of nulls, not a list of functions that evaluate to null.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just learned about another list function that wouldn't evaluate the function.

```
List.Zip(
    {
        ColumnNameList,
        List.Repeat(
            {each null},
            List.Count(ColumnNameList)
        )
    }
)
```